# How do i get Django form fields to work in my custom html create post model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Here is my views for create post..i would really appreciate a solution on how to fit the form field in mine Html code.**

```
def create_post(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user_name = user
            data.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Posted Successfully')
            return redirect('feed')
    else:
        form = NewPostForm()
    context['NewPostForm'] = form
    return render(request, 'feed/feed.html', context)
```

**Here is my forms model, how do I access the form fields in my html code below without having to  use the form variables like this {{form.as_p}}?**

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('description', 'pic', 'tags',)

class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('comment',)
```

Here is my HTML code for the post.

```
<div id="create-post-modal" class="create-post" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body uk-margin-auto-vertical rounded-lg p-0 lg:w-5/12 relative shadow-2xl uk-animation-slide-bottom-small">

        <div class="text-center py-4 border-b">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold"> Create Post </h3>
            <button class="uk-modal-close-default bg-gray-100 rounded-full p-2.5 m-1 right-2"  uk-close uk-tooltip="title: Close ; pos: bottom ;offset:7"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-1 items-start space-x-4 p-5">
            <img src="{{ user.profile_pic.url }}" class="bg-gray-200 border border-white rounded-full w-11 h-11">
            <div class="flex-1 pt-2">
                <form method="POST" id="post_form">{% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        <textarea name="description" id="id_description" class="uk-textare text-black shadow-none focus:shadow-none text-xl font-medium resize-none" rows="5" placeholder="What's Your Mind ? {{ user.first_name }}"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="bsolute bottom-0 p-4 space-x-4 w-full">
            <div class="flex bg-gray-50 border border-purple-100 rounded-2xl p-3 shadow-sm items-center">
                <div class="lg:block hidden"> Add to your post </div>
                <div class="flex flex-1 items-center lg:justify-end justify-center space-x-2">
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add your HTML.

Comment: I just added the HTML @AbdulAzizBarkat. thank you.

Comment: So you want to use only a specific field of your form instead the full form?

Comment: Yes i want  users to be able to post their feed and also images, Am actually using a custom HTML model which is not a form, it's been a challenge for me to fit the form in my custom  HTML code .

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML template you probably need this,

For feed text,

```
{{ NewPostForm.description }}
```

For image,

```
{{ NewPostForm.pic }}
```